# Compressing a list of intervals

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I need to compress a list of intervals into a smaller list. Let me explain:
For example I have a list containing intervals [1,4],[2,5],[5,7],[10,11],[13,20],[19,21] and i want to join the intersecting intervals and return a list [1,7],[10,11],[13,21] that transforming intersecting intervals into a single longer interval.
For this I wrote this method:

```
public List compress(List<Interval> intervals) {

    for (int j = 0; j < intervals.size(); j++) {
        Interval a = intervals.get(j);
        int aIndex = j;

        for (int i = 1 + aIndex; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            Interval b = intervals.get(i);

            if (a.intersects(b)) {
                //the union method return a union of two intervals. For example returns [1,7] for [1,4] and [2,5]
                intervals.add(j, a.union(b));
                intervals.remove(j+1);
                intervals.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return intervals;
}
```

This seems to work fine for the first pair of intervals that are checked but it stops there. That is the final output is a list containing [1, 5],[5, 7],[10, 11],[13, 20],[19, 21].
I have found that this may be a problem with illegal removing of elements from a list? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it?newreg=cc3f30e670e24cc2b05cd1fa2492906f
But I have no idea how to get around this.
Please can anyone give me a hint.

Notice: Sorry if I did anything wrong as this is my first post to stackoverflow. And thanks to anyone that will try to help.

UPDATE:
Here is the solution I found after  [Maraboc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/87685/maraboc) proposed to create a copy of the list and manipulate that one.
That seems to work.

```
public List compress(List<Interval> intervals) {

    List<Interval> man = intervals;
    for (int j = 0; j < intervals.size(); j++) {
        Interval a = intervals.get(j);
        int aIndex = j;

        for (int i = 1 + aIndex; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            Interval b = intervals.get(i);

            if (a.intersects(b)) {
                a = a.union(b);
                man.add(j,a);
                man.remove(j+1);
                man.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    return intervals;
}
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why don't you just use Guava and its Range class?

Comment: Note to the UPDATE : you are actually changing the same list, this line `List<Interval> man = intervals;` in reality only change name from intervals to man, but the list is the same. However creating copy and not change parameter is good idea, but you have to change that line to `List<Interval> man = new ArrayList<Interval>(intervals);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually NOT using iterator, you are using for-cycles and select elements from list based on their position, therefore you do not have to be afraid of "I am not able to remove while iterating" issue.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question first to stackexchange by mistake. They redirected me to this place and the question was put on hold. But before that happened Maraboc[a link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/87685/maraboc
) 
Helped with an idea. He told me to create a new list and modify that one. I did that and it seems to work. The updated solution will be in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it I took an existing [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and added a `minimise` method that seems to work nicely.

```
/**
 * Title: IntervlTree
 *
 * Description: Implements a static Interval Tree. i.e. adding and removal are not possible.
 *
 * This implementation uses longs to bound the intervals but could just as easily use doubles or any other linear value.
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 * @version 1.0
 * @param <T> - The Intervals to work with.
 */
public class IntervalTree<T extends IntervalTree.Interval> {
    // My intervals.

    private final List<T> intervals;
    // My center value. All my intervals contain this center.
    private final long center;
    // My interval range.
    private final long lBound;
    private final long uBound;
    // My left tree. All intervals that end below my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> left;
    // My right tree. All intervals that start above my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> right;

    public IntervalTree(List<T> intervals) {
        if (intervals == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // Initially, my root contains all intervals.
        this.intervals = intervals;

        // Find my center.
        center = findCenter();

        /*
         * Builds lefts out of all intervals that end below my center.
         * Builds rights out of all intervals that start above my center.
         * What remains contains all the intervals that contain my center.
         */
        // Lefts contains all intervals that end below my center point.
        final List<T> lefts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Rights contains all intervals that start above my center point.
        final List<T> rights = new ArrayList<>();

        long uB = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long lB = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            long start = i.getStart();
            long end = i.getEnd();
            if (end < center) {
                lefts.add(i);
            } else if (start > center) {
                rights.add(i);
            } else {
                // One of mine.
                lB = Math.min(lB, start);
                uB = Math.max(uB, end);
            }
        }

        // Remove all those not mine.
        intervals.removeAll(lefts);
        intervals.removeAll(rights);
        uBound = uB;
        lBound = lB;

        // Build the subtrees.
        left = lefts.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(lefts) : null;
        right = rights.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(rights) : null;

        // Build my ascending and descending arrays.
        /**
         * @todo Build my ascending and descending arrays.
         */
    }

    /*
     * Returns a list of all intervals containing the point.
     */
    List<T> query(long point) {
        // Check my range.
        if (point >= lBound) {
            if (point <= uBound) {
                // Gather all intersecting ones.
                List<T> found = intervals
                        .stream()
                        .filter((i) -> (i.getStart() <= point && point <= i.getEnd()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                // Gather others.
                if (point < center && left != null) {
                    found.addAll(left.query(point));
                }
                if (point > center && right != null) {
                    found.addAll(right.query(point));
                }

                return found;
            } else {
                // To right.
                return right != null ? right.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
            }
        } else {
            // To left.
            return left != null ? left.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Blends the two lists together.
     *
     * If the ends touch then make them one.
     *
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    static List<Interval> blend(List<Interval> a, List<Interval> b) {
        // Either empty - lreturn the other.
        if (a.isEmpty()) {
            return b;
        }
        if (b.isEmpty()) {
            return a;
        }
        Interval aEnd = a.get(a.size() - 1);
        Interval bStart = b.get(0);
        ArrayList<Interval> blended = new ArrayList<>();
        // Do they meet?
        if (aEnd.getEnd() >= bStart.getStart() - 1) {
            // Yes! merge them.
            // Remove the last.
            blended.addAll(a.subList(0, a.size() - 1));
            // Add a combined one.
            blended.add(new SimpleInterval(aEnd.getStart(), bStart.getEnd()));
            // Add all but the first.
            blended.addAll(b.subList(1, b.size()));
        } else {
            // Just join them.
            blended.addAll(a);
            blended.addAll(b);
        }
        return blended;
    }

    static List<Interval> blend(List<Interval> a, List<Interval> b, List<Interval>... more) {
        List<Interval> blended = blend(a, b);
        for (List<Interval> l : more) {
            blended = blend(blended, l);
        }
        return blended;
    }

    List<Interval> minimise() {
        // Calculate min of left and right.
        List<Interval> minLeft = left != null ? left.minimise() : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        List<Interval> minRight = right != null ? right.minimise() : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        // My contribution.
        long meLeft = minLeft.isEmpty() ? lBound : Math.max(lBound, minLeft.get(minLeft.size() - 1).getEnd());
        long meRight = minRight.isEmpty() ? uBound : Math.min(uBound, minRight.get(0).getEnd());
        return blend(minLeft,
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleInterval(meLeft, meRight)),
                minRight);
    }

    private long findCenter() {
        //return average();
        return median();
    }

    protected long median() {
        if (intervals.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Choose the median of all centers. Could choose just ends etc or anything.
        long[] points = new long[intervals.size()];
        int x = 0;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            // Take the mid point.
            points[x++] = (i.getStart() + i.getEnd()) / 2;
        }
        Arrays.sort(points);
        return points[points.length / 2];
    }

    /*
     * What an interval looks like.
     */
    public interface Interval {

        public long getStart();

        public long getEnd();
    }

    /*
     * A simple implemementation of an interval.
     */
    public static class SimpleInterval implements Interval {

        private final long start;
        private final long end;

        public SimpleInterval(long start, long end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public long getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        @Override
        public long getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + start + "," + end + "}";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test code.
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * @todo Needs MUCH more rigorous testing.
         */
        // Test data.
        long[][] data = {
            {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {5, 7}, {10, 11}, {13, 20}, {19, 21},};
        List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long[] pair : data) {
            intervals.add(new SimpleInterval(pair[0], pair[1]));
        }
        // Build it.
        IntervalTree<Interval> test = new IntervalTree<>(intervals);

        // Check minimise.
        List<Interval> min = test.minimise();
        System.out.println("Minimise test: ---");
        System.out.println(min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your algorithm to work, the intervals must be sorted, say by start.

Then the `for-i` loop can make `a` the longest possible interval.

```
       if (a.intersects(b)) {
            a = a.union(b);
            intervals.remove(i);
            --i; // So we remain at old i value.
        }
    } // for i
    intervals.set(j, a);
```

The reason for these requirements is that intervals A, B, C might form one long interval ABC, whereas C. B, A might.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem is that when you remove an element from the list, then all subsequent elements will be shifted. At around `j` I'm guessing it doesn't change because you insert then remove an item at the same location. But the removal at position `i` will shift all elements in the list.

What you could be doing, instead of removing the elements, is to put a null value at that position, so that the indices remain the same. You will then have to perform a final pass to remove null elements from the array (and check for nulls before comparing).

You could also run your inner loop backwards (from max `i` down to `j`) so that any element that gets shifted after `i` has already been processed.